# Is it possible to add unique 'field' in Supersized plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, supersized

Im using Supersized jQuery plugin (http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) to show my own photos to the visitors. The visitor can purchase every image on the site, so I decided to add a **Buy Now** button.

I would like to use PayPal for this, and I found an easy solution for that. The problem is with the buy now button, because every image has unique price, so I need to change the price parameter in the anchor's **href** attribute. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO, just a heads up but it's best to include any related code you already have and/or include a Fiddle that replicates you're problem.

If you're looking to add some information to a anchor href attribute then you can do something like the below.

The price could be included in a `data-` attribute on the image.

```
<img src="your/image/source.jpg" data-price="100" />
```

You could then include a click handler to the buy now button that retrieves price from the closest image and then adds it to the `href` attribute.

```
$('.buynow').on('click', function(){
   //Find closest image
   closestImage = $(this).closest('img');
   //Get the price
   imagePrice = closestImage.data('price');
   //Add the price to the href of the .buynow button
   $(this).attr('href','http://yourpaypalscreen.com/' + imagePrice + '/etc');
});
```

Please note this isn't a working solution but an example to get you started.